# how to send file in a specific folder in ssis by script task

Tags: ssis, msbi

i want to use script task in ssis to send file in a specific folder after processing how can i do it ? 
Thank u

Comment: You can use SSIS to move a file to a new folder (I actually recommend using 2 objects copy then delete vs 1 move)

Comment: Do you mean "send" an email with an attachment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the file shouldn't be a problem. [Take a look at this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.move?view=netframework-4.8).  You can pass in the path of files as variables.

```
    using System.IO;
    string path = (string)Dts.Variables["User::path1"].Value;;
    string path2 = (string)Dts.Variables["User::path2"].Value;;
    try 
    {

        // Ensure that the target does not exist.
        if (File.Exists(path2)) 
        File.Delete(path2);

        // Move the file.
        File.Move(path, path2);

    }
```

Comment: don't forget to add using System.IO; or use System.IO.File.Delete()

Comment: Thank u it's great